# Insert into table 10000 rows by 10000 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, request

I am doing a query that retrieves 450 million rows, every time I run it I get an 'Active Transaction Full' error message.

I want to insert 10,000 rows by 10,000 rows on my table, instead of trying to insert all at once, is it possible please?

My query :

```
INSERT INTO ZED_COTIS.stockdenorm.[DossierRecouvrement_Ind]  
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.*   
    FROM 
        STOCK_Pleiade.stock.TDossierRecouvrement A      
    INNER JOIN 
        STOCK_Pleiade.stock.TClientIndividuel B ON A.RefUnClient = B.OID
```

Comment: Is the source table partitioned?

Comment: No it is not partitioned :(

Comment: Mind you: if your transaction affects (updates/inserts) more than 5000 rows at once, SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and **exclusively lock** the entire table - so no one will be able to run even "harmless" `SELECT` queries on it. Fine if you have a downtime window - no so fine if your system needs to be up at all times ...

Comment: This query is massively suspect: you have a `DISTINCT` over all columns, which means it's going to be really slow, and you only select from one table even though you join two